# Tomorrow we will announce a winner! Or "the winner"?

Tags: articles

The voting is running now, so we don't know yet who is a/the winner.

1. Tomorrow we will announce **a** winner!
2. Tomorrow we will announce **the** winner!

Which one is correct?

Comment: In this specific case, both versions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The winner if there is only one winner.

A winner if there are going to be more winners at a later date.

Tomorrow we will announce a winner and the next day we will announce another winner.

Comment: OTOH, you can have "the winner of this week's lottery" and "the winner of last week's lottery".